# Hive > insert overwrite table / local directory doen't work

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive, overwrite

trying to join two tables and store the output in some table or local directory

map reduce job is success but nothing comes up in the output path / table.
can some one help me ?

```
hive> insert overwrite table order_result select e.emp_id as emp_id, count(distinct p.product_id) as product_id, sum(p.quantity) as quantity  from emp e join orders p on e.emp_id = p.emp_id group by e.emp_id order by quantity desc, product_id asc;
Total jobs = 3
Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1438631656520_0053, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1438631656520_0053/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1438631656520_0053
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 3; number of reducers: 1
2015-08-04 07:45:28,470 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-08-04 07:45:58,648 Stage-1 map = 22%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 11.62 sec
2015-08-04 07:46:01,302 Stage-1 map = 33%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 12.05 sec






MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 0 msec
Ended Job = job_1438631656520_0055
Loading data to table test_join.order_result
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
Deleted hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test_join.db/order_result
Table test_join.order_result stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=0, rawDataSize=0]
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 3  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 305.34 sec   HDFS Read: 354101279 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.76 sec   HDFS Read: 462 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS
Job 2: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.0 sec   HDFS Read: 462 HDFS Write: 48 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 5 minutes 11 seconds 100 msec
OK
Time taken: 817.424 seconds
hive> select * from order_result;
OK
Time taken: 0.146 seconds
```

Comment: Did you check that if there is data in the HDFS? Use the command hadoop fs -du -h to check. Please let me know if you can see data in your directory that you defined as a location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u check the query if you are getting output or not, as per the MR log which was shared, could see the Input Data Size was 354101279 where as output is only 96

> HDFS Read: 354101279 HDFS Write: 96 SUCCESS

belive the query is working fine but not producing any output.

it could be reason like.

> Both Input Table is having data but the Data Type for emp_id is not
>   corrent or not matching

Comment: Datatype of the emp_id in both the tables is same and is 'int';

Comment: On that case please check the query with sample output, as the size defines as output is coming NULL..

Comment: Yeah, Query is fine but problem is with data inside the table...it has some null columns.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the data in DB tables; it has some NULL values;
If anyone face the same issue; check the data inside the tables is as per your requirement and don't have any null values.